# Is it safe to substitute html <script src="xxx.js"> 'includes' with $.getScript(...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, include

(I am still very new to Javascript and JQuery) I am trying to keep my code clean by creating one js file per html file. I also have a couple of common js file containing code used by page-specific js files.

I was searching for solutions to import/include other js files in a given js file and I came accross this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file). It refers to `$.getScript()`.

Instead of using multiple `<script src="xxx.js"></script>` as imports/includes in my html pages, could I move them to my js files and use `$.getScript(...)` instead? I mean, is it safe? Is it a good practice?

**EDIT**

Is it safe regarding cyclic references?

**EDIT II**

To make it more clear, let's imagine I have `a1.js`, `a2.js` and `a3.js`.

For `a1.js`:

```
$.getScript("a2.js");
$.getScript("a3.js");
...
```

For `a2.js`:

```
$.getScript("a3.js");
...
```

For `a3.js`:

```
$.getScript("a2.js");
...
```

There is a potential infinite loop between `a2.js` and `a3.js`. Should I handle it with something like this in each js file:

```
var vari;

if (typeof vari === 'undefined') {
    vari = 1;
}
```

Comment: that's what google.load() does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding good Practice that answer is as always... it depends.

**Your Page Style**

Contra:

- If you for example use a script to substitute some page fonts, the effect will be that the font change will be even more visible for the user.
- If your script changes the height of some elements, this will be very noticeable.

PRO:

- If you load a Script to handle a specific form, that the user first has to edit, there is no problem at all
- If you load a Script that starts animation that can be substituted with a single loading animation you can do this.
- If your page is a application with many views and models, you can use `getScript` like `getJson`, in this case your page speed will greatly improve.

**Your Coding Style**

- Not every Page and Script is structured to be used this way. JQuery's  `$(document).ready()` fires every registered handler once, even after the event occurred. This does not necessarily mean every handler works this way, certainly not the DOM2 Events.
- If you have anywhere inline Scripts it will no longer work.
- You can no longer guarantee a certain order your initialization code will have, so you can run in problems have to add more checks, that e.g. a expectedly visible container is still visible.

**Whats the reward?**

On high performance pages, you gain some thats clear. But script tags at the end of the page can do the same thing with half the work (mainly: remove inline scripts). In my opinion `getScript` is something like a last reward, you should not overuse it, because the potential to not only scare other developers but also your customers away is clearly there. I would only use it in the environment of a web application, because here are the real benefits

**UPDATE** response to your comment

Using getScript on your page should look like this:

```
//since you need it there will be some kind of wrapper
var initClosure = function() {...}

if(typeof optionalNamespace == 'undefined') {
    $.getScript('/foo.js', initClosure);
} else {
    initClosure();
}
```

All depending code is in initClosure, and you check a namespace, or variable name (even something like `window['blub']` or simply `blub` will work). You will need this, since the on `getScript` depending function, wich typically sets default values or appends something to the dom should only be called once.

Nevertheless I don't really see the point in cyclic references, because this would mean:

load script 1 -> wait -> loaded ->load script 2 -> wait ->loaded -> [...] ->load script 1

This situation should be avoided for at least 2 reasons

- The browser can not predict this. If there are several script tags, your browser will take care of parallel downloads, so the overall speed (simplified & rough) is the time the biggest file will need to load. In my Example it will take the sum of the script loads.
- Initialization of your scripts will be handled twice, so any state will get lost.

Comment: What is your answer to the main question? Yes or No? I have updated the question with more information to explain the issue.

Comment: OH... If you are thinking about loading in a hierarchical  order the answer is **no**. Loading 3 scripts without any possibility for parallelization as really slow. I think a good rule of thumb is: If the user klicks a button he expects to wait for something, so you can load a script, if your scripts are expecting something that isn't there, change your scripts.

Comment: Ok, but I see a contradiction here. How come it would be safe to load js files with circular references from the HTML page and not with $.getScript() for js files instead?

Comment: I have edited a little bit, but I am not sure I really got the _files with circular references from the HTML_ completely...

Comment: I am referring to the case where function f1 belonging to a1.js calls f2 belonging to a2.js, and where f2 calls f1 too.

Comment: Ok, I found out about wro4j and Google's Closure compiler, so this point is becoming moot.